# Access iOS device's camera stream by using web application

Tags: ios, video, camera, stream, webrtc

My aim is to be able to access iOS device's camera stream and transmit it to a server in real time. The important point is  I am not trying to access photo/video library, neither take a photo/video. (like by using `<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera">` )

I am trying to access video stream in Safari browser. For other modern browsers, I can use WebRTC but it is not valid for Safari as well as Flash. Is there any other option for me to capture iOS device's camera stream to web application in real time? (Like an equivalent of Flash / WebRTC? )

Comment: No, there is no option for this right now. The platform is simply too locked down, and there is no native browser support.

Comment: Thanks. So, the only option is to force user to install some custom app..